# How can I have a lifetime dependency without a reference?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm wrapping a C library that has `context` and `device` objects. The `context` object needs to outlive the `device` object because the `device` keeps an internal reference to the `context`.

To express this, I use a `PhantomData` field in the `Device` wrapper:

```
use std::marker::PhantomData;

struct Context;

impl Context {
    fn open_device<'a>(&'a self) -> Device<'a> {
        Device { _context: PhantomData, }
    }
}

struct Device<'a> {
    _context: PhantomData<&'a Context>,
}
```

Now, in my client code, I would like to have a struct that holds both the `Context` and `Device` objects. But because the `Device` holds a reference (a fake one) to the `Context`, I'm not able to do this (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32300132/why-cant-i-store-a-value-and-a-reference-to-that-value-in-the-same-struct) question). But this is an unnecessary restriction because the `Device` struct doesn't actually contain a reference to the `Context`.

So how can I tie the lifetime of the `Device` to the lifetime of the `Context` in a way that would allow me to hold both of them in a struct?

Answer (score 3):

As of today, Rust is not able to express a lifetime that refers to an object defined in the same struct, so it's impossible to declare the proper lifetime for the `Device` member.

Instead of storing both objects directly in the struct, could you instead store references to these structs? (This won't work if you want to make a function that returns that struct.)

```
struct Both<'a: 'b, 'b> {
    context: &'a Context,
    device: &'b Device<'a>,
}
```

Another option is to declare the `Device` as having a `Context` with `'static` lifetime (I'm using `'static` because it's the only lifetime with a name), but always using a method to "cast" the `Device` into one with appropriate lifetime parameters, rather than using the field directly.

```
struct Both {
    context: Context,
    device: Device<'static>,
}

impl Both {
    fn get_device<'a>(&'a self) -> &'a Device<'a> {
        &self.device
    }
}
```

Actually, thanks to lifetime elision, it is not necessary to specify the lifetime parameters explicitly on `get_device` (likewise for your `open_device` method, by the way):

```
impl Both {
    fn get_device(&self) -> &Device {
        &self.device
    }
}
```

There's just a gotcha: you need to use `transmute` to lie about the device's lifetime parameter when you initialize the struct.

```
use std::mem;

fn get_both() -> Both {
    let context = Context; // could also be a parameter
    let device: Device<'static> = unsafe { mem::transmute(context.open_device()) };
    Both {
        context: context,
        device: device,
    }
}
```

You might also want to consider having the `Both` struct containing a `Device` that has no lifetime parameter, then wrapping that in another struct that does have a lifetime parameter and returning that from a method.

```
use std::marker::PhantomData;
use std::mem;

struct Context;

impl Context {
    fn open_device(&self) -> Device {
        Device
    }
}

struct Device;

struct DeviceWrapper<'a> {
    _context: PhantomData<&'a Context>,
    device: &'a Device,
}

struct Both {
    context: Context,
    device: Device,
}

impl Both {
    fn get_device(&self) -> DeviceWrapper {
        DeviceWrapper { _context: PhantomData, device: &self.device }
    }
}

fn get_both() -> Both {
    let context = Context;
    let device = context.open_device();
    Both {
        context: context,
        device: device,
    }
}
```

(In fact, the `DeviceWrapper` probably doesn't need the `_context` member, since the `DeviceWrapper`'s lifetime is tied to that of the `Both` already.)

Comment: Do you know where in the rfcs github the discussion about binding lifetime to that of another member in the same instance can be found?